# Tkinter buttons not performing command

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, tkinter

I am trying to create a counter for Jeopardy so that my Mom and I can keep score. Currently the program that I am creating is assigning the values to variables and then not performing the command when I press the button in the window. I am running Python 2.7.13.`
    import Tkinter as tk

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Jeopardy Scores")

def ChangeScore(User,Value):
    if User == 1:
         Score = int(JScore.get())
         JScore.set(Score + Value)
         #J = JScore.get()
         #print J
         #SayHi()

    else:
         Score = int(MScore.get())
         MScore.set(Score + Value)
         #M = MScore.get()
         #print M
         #SayHi()

#def SayHi(*args):
    #print 'hi'

MainFrame = tk.Frame(root)
MainFrame.grid(column=0, row=0)
MainFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
MainFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

JScore = tk.StringVar()
MScore = tk.StringVar()
JScore.set(0)
MScore.set(0)


JL = tk.Label(MainFrame, text = "Joey's Score", padx = 10, pady = 2)
JL.config(bg = 'blue', fg = 'yellow', font = ('Arial',30, 'bold'))
JL.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
ML = tk.Label(MainFrame, text = "Mom's Score", padx = 10, pady = 2)
ML.config(bg = 'blue', fg = 'yellow', font = ('Arial',30, 'bold'))
ML.grid(column = 1, row = 0)



JSS = tk.Label(MainFrame, textvariable=JScore ,padx = 122)
JSS.config(bg = 'blue', fg = 'yellow', font = ('Arial',30, 'bold'))
JSS.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

MSS = tk.Label(MainFrame, textvariable = MScore,padx = 122)
MSS.config(bg = 'blue', fg = 'yellow', font = ('Arial',30, 'bold'))
MSS.grid(column = 1, row = 1)


for i in range(1,6):
    Score = tk.IntVar()
    Score.set(i*200)
    Score1 = 200*i
    JButton = tk.Button(MainFrame, textvariable = Score, command = 
                        ChangeScore(1,Score1))
    JButton.grid(column = 0, row = 1+i)
    MButton = tk.Button(MainFrame, textvariable = Score, command = 
                        ChangeScore(2,Score1))
    MButton.grid(column = 1, row = 1+i)

JButton = tk.Button(MainFrame, text = '400', command = ChangeScore(1,400))
JButton.grid(column = 0, row = 7)


root.mainloop()
```

The code runs and produces this Window

[image]

Note that no buttons have been pressed when the picture was taken. It appears that all the buttons are 'being pressed' when the code runs and then nothing happens when i press the buttons afterwards.

I have no experience with Tkinter beyond the small information that has allowed me to do this and I have a bit more experience with Python. I am mainly doing this as an excerise for myself to improve my coding and to acutally use for Jeopardy!. Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the `command` parameter for `Button` should be a callable. You should not call the function yourself and pass the return value to it. Instead, you provide a function that is to be called later.

So change you code to things like

```
command=lambda: ChangeScore(1, 400)
```

to create a lambda to be called later will solve the problem.